# Node Express Registration function not working

Tags: node.js, express, promise, async-await

This function is a registration function that:
1) checks whether the email entered in the form already exists in the database
2) hashs the password if the email doesn't exist
3) Creates a user instance and saves the user to mongo collection
4) Sends a verification token to the registered email to verify the account

I am experiencing an error in (3) where the .catch is called after attempting to save user to the database, ie. the promise is unable to resolve. I tried taking out the promise after `const newUser = new User({...})` and everything up to that point functions properly. So I have narrowed down to error to: the `newUser` cannot be saved to the collection. I am suspecting that I am incorrectly passing the parameters through each function inside `async.waterfall()`, but I am hoping for any insight into potential problems.

`auth.js`

```
const async = require("async");
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

const User = require("..models/User").Model;

controller.register = (req, res) => {
    // grab user data from registration form body
    const { fname, lname, email, password } = req.body;

    const validateEmail = (callback) => {
        User.findOne({ "email.address": email})
        .then(user => {
            if(user) {
                return res.status(403).json({
                    error: "This is email is already associated with a registered account"
                });
            } else {
                callback(null, fname, lname, email, password);
            };
        })
        .catch(err => {
            return res.status(500).json({
                errors: err.message || "The server experienced an error while validating this email"
            });
        });
    };

    // hash password from the form and pass form data to the database collection
    const hashPassword = (fname, lname, email, password, callback) => {
        bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
            bcrypt.hash("", salt, (err, hash) => {
                if(err) {
                    return res.status(500).json({
                        message: "The server was unable to hash your password",
                        errors: err
                    });
                } else {
                    password = hash;

                    callback(null, fname, lname, email, hash);
                };
            });
        });
    };

    const registerUser = (fname, lname, email, hash, callback) => {
        // create user instance from form data and hashed password
        const newUser = new User({    
            "name.first": fname,
            "name.last": lname,
            "email.address": email,
            password: hash
        });

        // save user to database collection and pass user info to next function
        newUser.save()
        .then(user => {
            callback(null, user);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            return res.status(500).json({
                success: false,
                message: err.messsage || "An error occured while registering your new account"
            });
        });
    };

    const sendVerificationEmail = (user, callback) => {
        // use nodemailer to send an verification token to the registered email address to verify the new account
    };

    // run series of functions above
    async.waterfall([
        validateEmail, // check whether registered email is already in database
        hashPassword, // if not, hash the password
        registerUser, // save the new user to the database collection
        sendVerificationEmail // send verification token to email to verify the account
    ], (err, results) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).json({
                message: "The server was unable to complete your request",
                errors: err
            });
        } else {
            return res.status(201).json(results);
        }
    });
}
```

Here is my Users model for reference:
`User.js`

```
const Schema = require("mongoose").Schema;
const model = require("mongoose").model;

const UserSchema = new Schema({
    _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    name: {
        first: {type: String, required: true},
        last: {type: String, required: true}
    },
    email: {
        address: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
        verified: {type: Boolean, default: false}
    },
    password: {type: String, required: true, minlength: 6}, 
});

module.exports = {
    Schema: UserSchema,
    Model: model("User", UserSchema)
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code for User model?

Comment: @SuleymanSah done, please see again!

Comment: Can you try this? const newUser = new User({
  name: {
    first: fName,
    last: lname
  },
  email: {
    address: email
  },
  password: hash
});

Comment: That definitely was an error! I just fixed newUser however I'm still getting the same error

Comment: what does err logs here?  .catch(err => {  console.log(err) ...  in newUser.save()

Comment: By the way  I had a typo in fName, it should have been fname here:  const newUser = new User({
  name: {
    first: fname,
    last: lname
  },
  email: {
    address: email
  },
  password: hash
});

Comment: no worries, I saw what you meant. and the .catch after the user.save() is called, so it returns return res.status(500).json({
                success: false,
                message: err.messsage || "An error occured while registering your new account"
            }); which sends "{sucess: false , message:"An error occured while registering your new account}"" to the client

Comment: I am using React and Redux on the client side; I think there are errors managing the state that are triggering the error. Thanks for your pointers though! I believe its leading me in the right direction

Comment: console.log(err)   before return res.status(500) will give much info about the error.